# ¿Es verdad que el SQL es diferente en los SGBD?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, mongodb

Trabajo desde hace algún tiempo con MySQL, y yo entiendo que la mayoría de SGBD trabajan con el lenguaje de SQL, el inconveniente que me surge es cuando leo en algunas partes que en los SGBD la sintaxis del SQL es un poco diferente y varía un poco, eso me confunde porque pienso yo que ya que tienen SQL debería ser igual para todos **¿Es verdad que el SQL es diferente en los SGBD?** **¿Me pueden pasar el enlace de alguna página para entender mejor esto por favor?**

Comment: Sí que hay diferencias de sintaxis entre unos SGBD y otros (se me ocurre, si no recuerdo mal, en MySQL se usan las comillas hacia atrás ` para cadenas literales en nombres de tabla o columna y en SQL Server son los corchetes []). Pero, en general, los conceptos básicos de SQL van a ser los mismos (o muy parecidos) en todos. Algo parecido (y que se me perdone la comparación) a los navegadores web: todos muestran HTML, pero cada uno lo interpreta de una manera algo diferente o tiene cosas propias.

Comment: Al final de la primer sección de [SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) mencionan eso.

Comment: Esta pregunta está en el límite de la temática del sitio: sí, es sobre programación; pero es amplia y no muestra trabajo de investigación (una búsqueda rápida en Google mostrará resultados decentes que resuelven la pregunta.) Lee [ask] para más información.

Comment: Ningún motor de base de datos implementa SQL tal cual como está definido en los estándares [a través del tiempo]. Todos los motores implementan las secciones que son más importantes para ellos y dejan de lado otras que consideran menos relevantes. Y no solo eso: cada motor implementa muchas extensiones no estándares. Es interesante considerar que por un lado el no ceñirse al estándar confunde a programadores nuevos; por otro lado fomenta la innovación en el campo.